# Ambiguous sentence propositional logic interoperation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Gordan has made 100 dishes but I have not had one of them.

Does this sentence have any ambiguity?
I think it's straight forward. There is only one interperation in form of a and not b.
Can anyone find another interperation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Gordan has made 100 dishes but I have not had one of them.

Have you not had *any* from the 100, or is there *only one* dish from the 100 that you have not had?

Though the statement is ambiguous, the *usual* interpretation is the former.

Answer (score 2):

yes. It could mean that you have not had any of them, that was what I first thought. If you go back enough decades, this meaning would have demanded different English grammar, i have had not one of them.

Then I figured that there might be a special dish, you had the other 99 but never had this one.

I have had not a single bad experience with them.

I have had not a single response from anyone on this issue.

I have had not a single cold, sinus infection, etc.

I have had not one word from her

I have had not one but two exceptional customer service encounters

https://www.poetrynook.com/poem/i-have-had-not-one-word-her

Comment: Though how you gonna write down the propositional logic translation?